# Коротка відповідь на питання "О котрій годині це було?"

Tags: вживання-слів, позначення-часу

Припустимо щось сталося з 10:00 до 11:00, або з 22:00 до 23:00.

Російською я можу сказати:

> Это было в десять часов (утра/вечера/ночи), точнее в десять двадцать
>   семь/ десять пятьдесят семь

Українською повні версії звучать [так](http://svitslova.com/mova/morpho/4392-2014-11-28-18-06-27.html)

> 16.15
>
> - **четверта** (шістнадцята) година п'ятнадцять хвилин
> - п'ятнадцять хвилин по **четвертій** (шістнадцятій)
> - п'ятнадцять хвилин на **п’яту** (сімнадцяту)
> - чверть по **четвертій** (шістнадцятій)
> - чверть на **п’яту** (сімнадцяту)
>
> 20.45
>
> - двадцята (**восьма**) година сорок п’ять хвилин
> - п'ятнадцять хвилин до **дев’ятої** (двадцять першої)
> - чверть до **дев’ятої** (двадцять першої)
> - за п'ятнадцять хвилин **дев’ята** (двадцять перша)
> - за чверть **дев’ята** (двадцять перша)

Якщо подія сталася між 10 та 11 годинами, чи можна коротко сказати о котрій це було? Якщо можна, то це сталося **о 10-ій** чи **об 11-ій**?

Comment: 1) "о**б** одинадцятій". 2) це залежить від того ближче до якої години ця подія відбулася - ближче до десятої - значить "о десятій", ближче до одинадцятої - значить "об одинадцятій". Ступінь близькості залежить від того хто каже. Працівник що виїхав на роботу о 10.40 може сказати що це була "десята година", а начальник заперечить що 10.40 це вже одинадцята.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Знайшов ["Уроки державної мови"](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/248.htm) від редактору журналу "Хрещатик" Б П. Рогози. Він пояснює ситуацію з майбутнім часом.

> Коли потрібно сказати не про точно визначений час, а лиш приблизно
>   назвати період між двома годинами, маємо тоді, як радив Борис
>   Антоненко-Давидович, ставити перед порядковим числівником прийменник
>   на: “*Ой сплю годину, сплю і другу, а вже повертає та на третю*” (Семен
>   Гулак-Артемовський).
>
> Отож російську фразу “Я приду в пятом часу” треба
>   перекласти українською: “**Я прийду на п’яту годину**”, а не “**Я прийду о
>   п’ятій годині**”, бо це означає вже точний, а не приблизний час.

Т.т. у контексті нашого прикладу - "**Це буде на десяту, точніше на десяту п'ятнадцять/сорок п'ять"**

Там же знаходимо

> Ілюстрації з творів майстрів слова, які репрезентують різні місцевості
>   та різні історичні періоди, свідчать, що ця мовна конструкція усталена
>   й загальноукраїнська. “**Вставши о восьмій, він поснідав**”, “**Пішов о
>   дванадцятій замість о першій**” (Іван Франко), “**Вранці прокидаємось
>   близько десятої години**” (Леся Українка), “**Вже пізно, друга година**”,
>   “**Кінчаємо роботу о третій годині**” (Михайло Коцюбинський), “**Була тільки
>   п’ята година, а навкруги сутеніло**” (Олесь Гончар), “**Завтра об
>   одинадцятій на мене чекатиме інженер**” (Юрій Смолич). У таких фразах
>   порядкові числівники означають не проміжок часу між двома годинами,
>   як, скажімо, в російських висловах *в пятом часу, в одиннадцатом*, а
>   точно визначену годину, що по-російськи буде: *в пять часов, в
>   одиннадцать часов*.

Але людині властиво помилятися, особливо щодо минулих подій. Т.т. навіть російське *Это было в одиннадцать часов* не гарантує, що події відбулися точно об 11:00. Навпаки, людина, що вживає цей вираз російською, часто має на увазі,що це було приблизно об 11-й.

Т.т. у контексті нашого прикладу можна сказати - "**Це було о десятій, точніше п'ятнадцять хвилин по десятій"**. Але для 10:45 варто вже казати- "**Це було об одинадцятій, точніше за п'ятнадцять хвилин одинадцята"**. Такий тонкий семантичний нюанс.