# Як правильно казати поточний час?

Tags: відмінювання

Коли хтось спитає: "Котра зараз година?" Як правильно відповідати?

0:01 - `нуль годин одна хвилина` чи `нульова година одна хвилина`?

1:01 - `перша година одна хвилина` чи `одна година одна хвилина`?

2:00 - `друга година рівно` чи `дві години нуль хвилин`?

І як прийнято казати на години після полудня? `Перша пополудні` чи `тринадцята година`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2825/240

Comment: Not exactly. This question is about telling current time on the clock, not about past or future time.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2829/240 (just in case: I'm not urging you to delete the question or anything like that, just trying to help those who will answer it and you to understand everything better. I mean, no need to research it twice if some part of the information is already properly researched).

Comment: [Тут](ftp://ftp.nas.gov.ua/akademperiodyka/Downloads/Visnyk_NANU/downloads/2007/1/a6.pdf) на с. 45 М. Вакуленко наголошує на нелогічності вживання порядкових числівників для годин (тобто, на його думку, правильніше «дві години», ніж «друга година»). Втім не можу не зазначити, що його погляд вибивається із безлічі джерел, що постулюють класичне «друга година». Також зазначу, що класичні способи розраховані на приблизний час (раніше не було точних годинників); якщо на годиннику 1 хвилина і це важливо, то більшість скаже просто «тринадцять нуль один» чи «один нуль один»; НМД.

Comment: @Sasha «нуль одна», мабуть, бо ж хвилина

Comment: @Yola, довго думав над цим, ще коли писав коментар. Я припускаю, що можливі обидва варіанти — залежно від того, наскільки мовець зосереджений на буквальному прочитанні цифр. Якщо не дуже зациклений, то може бути й «тринадцят**а** [година] нуль одна [хвилина]» — але я хотів показати «найзосередженіший» варіант.

Answer (score 3):

Згідно з [експрес-уроків української мови](//youtube.com/watch?v=zaTRsN-S5yg) Олександра Авраменка кажемо, приклади:

**8:50** — **восьма година пʼятдесят хвилин** або коротко **восьма пʼятдесят**. В жодному разі не можна казати вісім годин пʼятдесят хвилин! Називаючи годину подтрібно використовувати порядковий числівник, а коли говоримо про хвилини — кількісний.

**15:10** — **пʼятнадцята година десять хвилин** або **пʼятнадцята десять**.

Однак **розмовна мова** дозволяє говорити про час й іншими способами, все залежить від розташування стрілки циферблата (див. відео від 1:48), наприклад: **десять хвилин на шосту** (5:10), **пʼятнадцять хвилин на третю** (2:15), **за десять хвилин шоста** (5:50) або ж **за двадцять хвилин п'ята** (4:40).

Також, якщо маємо **11:00**, то можемо сказати **одинадцята година рівно** чи **рівно одинадцята година**" і ніяк інакше. Можливий ще такий варіант, що якщо маємо **11:10**, то можна сказати **десять хвилин по одинадцятій**, а не лише **десять хвилин на дванадцяту**. 11:30 — **одинадцята (година) тридцять (хвилин)** або **пів на дванадцяту** (див. [джерело](//200baliv.com/yak-pravylno-hovoryty-pro-chas-ukrajinskoyu/)).

На рахунок **00:01** - згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83) **00:00** - це дванадцята (година) ночі або ж опівночі. За принципом наведеним вище кажемо: "**Дванадцята година ночі одна хвилина**".

Comment: А щодо «00:01»?

Comment: Питання це цікаве, і точної відповіді я не знайшов, але згідно до Вікіпедії, 00:00 - це дванадцята година, отож виходить, що можемо сказати дванадцята година одна хвилина.

Comment: @Sasha [Хвилина по [о\]північ[і\]](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&safe=off&q=хвилина+по+півночі).

Comment: @follower, це, мабуть, автору запитання якось сказати треба. Якщо Анатолій не схоче розширювати відповідь, може, створите окрему?

Comment: @Анатолій, а якщо 24-годинний формат часу, то як сказати `00:01`? Бо `дванадцята година одна хвилина` може трактуватися як `12:01` дня.

Comment: @Sasha, `хвилина по` - це більше розмовний стиль. А якщо дотримуватися суто технічного? Тобто зі словами `годин`, `хвилин`.

Comment: @user2513149, я думаю, «дванадцята година [ночі] одна хвилина».

Comment: @follower, це той самий М. Вакуленко, про якого я згадував [тут](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/4748#comment7452_4748). Його позиція однозначно варта уваги, але не впевнений, що це «мейнстрим».

Comment: Якщо не подобається слово "по" - можна вживати "після" натомість. Одна хвилина після дванадцятої або опівночі (якщо ви не хочете, щоб путали із денним часом доби.).